# Magento add company name to order and customer grid

Tags: magento

What I need is to show Company name instead of first and lastname whenever customer address is shown.

Besides that, I need to add company name to registration form, customer and order grid.

What is the best way(s) to achieve this?

Comment: In default magento, Company is not a mandatory field. Did you customized it as a mandatory field??

Comment: You can try to edit "Address Templates" in "System/Configuration/Customer Configuration".

Answer (score 1):

I was adding this today into some Magento store and saw this old question, maybe my answer will help somebody else. This will answer you only how to add company name into order grid. To do that you need to extend Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid class. Then you override _prepareCollection and _prepareColumns functions. This code is based on [this free extension](http://www.magebird.com/magento-extensions/company-name-in-admin-orders-grid.html)

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

    $tableName = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getTableName('sales_flat_order_address');                  
    $collection->getSelect()->join($tableName, "main_table.entity_id = $tableName.parent_id AND $tableName.address_type='billing'",array('company'));
    $this->setCollection($collection);               
    return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
} 

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumnAfter('company', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Company'),
        'index'     => 'company'
    ),'billing_name');   

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```